# How to remove the border around the image that is generated by <a>?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am developing an ASP.NET web application and I have some images in the images slider without any links, so now when I put the images between anchor tags I got a border (in a purple color) around each image just in the Internet Explorer and I don't know why. In Firefox, everything works fine. So how to fix that in the IE browser?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What slider?

if you want to remove borders from all the images in < a > tags
you can use the following css rule:

```
a img {
   border:none;
}
```

... every IE sometimes has problems with style="border-style:none"
use style="border:none" instead

Answer (score 3):

Set the `border-style` property to `none`.

```
img { border-style: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This example uses the style attribute to define the border style:

```
<a href="myurl" style="border: none;">    
<img src="someimage.jpg" .... />    
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a img {
    border: medium none;
}
```

Hope this helps.